# Could drugs promoting angiogenesis be used as a treatment for burn victims?

Tags: cell-biology, hematology

From what I've learned from my textbooks and in class lecutures it seems that inducing angiogenesis for people with severe burns would be an excellent way to speed up the healing process. Is this already being done? If so or if not what are (if any) challenges that are presented to doctors and surgeons trying to use this self-healing method?

Comment: good question, interesting idea... obviously angiogenesis is necessary for skin grafts to grow to previously burned and debrided areas. It loos like angiogenesis is measured/quantified in research in this area, but I'm not aware of actual drugs/pharmaceuticals that act in this way directly.

Comment: A quick [Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=angiogenesis+burn+healing) yields a number of papers looking at this through a variety of angiogenic factors such as leptin, EPO, and dextran hydrogel scaffolds, mainly by topical application.